# CodeIgniter set_message not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
public function doAssignerSU() {

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|alpha_numeric');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|alpha_numeric|min_length[4]');
    $this->form_validation->set_message('min_length','Minimum of 4 characters');
```

When I display my validation error in my view, it still displays the preset 'The {field} must be minimum of ..'

what's my mistake? Thanks in advance

Comment: @Parvez there's no error. It just doesn't set my custom message for the 'min_length' rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your custom message like this..

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|alpha_numeric|min_length[4]',array('min_length'=>'Minimum of 4 characters'));
```

**Hint:You can directly set your custom messages when setting rules.**

For more see [Codeigniter Form Validation](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html)

Comment: swear to god I've already typed this for like 5 times before posting the question. copying your line somehow managed to do the trick. anyway, thanks mate

Comment: glad to help you.You can directly set your custom `messages` when setting `rules`.Best of luck ahead.

Comment: @JorelAngeloMolato, yes, this is the answer when setting a message for a single element.  However, since `set_message()` is global, your original mistake was not placing it *above* `set_rules()`